# Set the default NSAppearance of an application

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

I can change the appearance of an NSWindow by setting the 'appearance' property. Is there any way of setting the default appearance for the whole application, so that I don't have to set it for each window?

Answer (score 0):

`NSApplication` has an `var appearance: NSAppearance?` property, and this cascades to windows and views through `effectiveAppearance`.